# Rails: hide property of inner object in jbuilder and show has_many's property in jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've the following JSON generated of a Post:

```
{  
   "comments":[  
      {  
         "created_at":"2015-09-07T23:04:46.000Z",
         "id":2,
         "post_id":32,
         "text":"sdfsdfdsf",
         "updated_at":"2015-09-07T23:04:46.000Z",
         "user_id":13
      }
   ],
   "id":32,
   "text":"xxxx",
   "user":{  
      "college_id":1,
      "created_at":"2015-09-06T21:37:06.000Z",
      "email":"mhewedy@hotmail.com",
      "gender":"m",
      "id":14,
      "name":"mhewedy",
      "password_digest":"$2a$10$shb6XUFtYnm0ctCPMEb88eDyXmw/jnhDMN65GVPr9Z19DalfOGJzC",
      "university_id":4,
      "updated_at":"2015-09-07T18:42:10.000Z",
      "user_type":"student",
      "username":"mhewedy5"
   }
}
```

Where `Post` belongs to a `User` and a `Post` has many `comments` where each comment belongs to a `User` (straight forward).

I want to display the `User` object under `comments` and hide the `password_digest` field from both `User` objects of the `Post` and the `Comment`.

I'am using the following jbuilder file:

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :text, :user, :comments
end
```

P.S. I cannot find enough resources for jbuilder online.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [another syntax](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) for building your nested JSON:

```
yourJSON = Jbuilder.new do |j|
  j.id @post.id
  j.text @post.text
  #(... other @post attributes ...)
  j.user do
    j.id @post.user.id
    j.email @post.user.email
    #(... other @post.user attributes ...)
  end
  j.comments @post.comments.each do |aComment|
    j.id aComment.id
    j.text aComment.text
    #(... other Comment attributes ...)
  end
end

render json: yourJSON.target!
```

this would generate the following JSON:

```
{
 id:1,
 text:"Post text",
 //(...)
 user: {
     id: 30,
     email: "user@email.com",
     //(...)
   },
comments[
    {
       id:2002
       text:"this is the comment text",
       //(...) 
    },
    {
       id:2003
       text:"this is the comment text",
       //(...) 
    },
    //(... other comments here ...) 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, can you suggest some detailed tutorial?

Comment: I fixed by the help of https://github.com/railscasts/320-jbuilder/blob/master/blog-after/app/views/articles/show.json.jbuilder. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by the help of RailsCasts: https://github.com/railscasts/320-jbuilder/blob/master/blog-after/app/views/articles/show.json.jbuilder

Watch the video on RailsCasts here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

```
json.(@posts) do |post|
  json.(post, :id, :text, :created_at)
  json.comment_count post.comments.size

  json.user do |json|
    json.(post.user, :id, :name, :gender, :college_id, :university_id, :user_type)
  end
end
```